# Sorting a list of char in Lisp

Tags: sorting, lisp

Is there a way to sort a list made of only characters in alphabetic order (from "a" to "z"), such as: (list c m a y k) => (list a c k m y)?

I didn't found a sort like that, so i thought this could solve the problem:

```
cl-prompt> (setq q (mapcar 'string '(c m a y k))) => ("C" "M" "A" "Y" "K")
cl-prompt> (sort q 'string<) => ("A" "C" "K" "M" "Y")
```

At this point i'm stuck, because by using the char converter the output will not be the list i want.
Example:

```
char (string 'a) 0 => #\A
```

And i will have a list made of: (#\A #\C #\K #\M #\Y), which is not the result i want.

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to be symbols rather than characters? As in `(let ((list (copy-list '(c m a y k)))) (sort list #'string<))` => `(A C K  M Y)`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've already tried this but the first it didn't work and i don't know why. So i tried something harder. Glad it's that simple.

Comment: `(c m a y k)` is not a list of characters. It is a list of symbols.

Comment: My bad. I used to think a list like (c m a y k) was a list of chars.

Comment: `(type-of #\a) => STANDARD-CHAR`, `(type-of 'a) => SYMBOL` You should [edit] your question to clarify whether you're looking for a list of characters, symbols, or something else, since right now, it looks like your question answers itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `(c m a y k)`, you have a list of symbols.
In the case of `(#\A #\C #\K #\M #\Y)`, you have a list of characters.

If you want to sort a list of symbols according to the symbol names, you can do (I am assuming the list is bound to the variable foo below):

```
(setq foo (sort foo #'string< :key #'symbol-name))
```

Note that the `:key #'symbol-name` could be argued to be superfluous, as `string<` actually operates on "string designators", but it is much clearer to a human reader that you are indeed intending to sort the list based on symbol names if you say so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One can convert characters to their ASCII numbers, sort the numbers and convert back to characters. Following is code in Racket, a Lisp/Scheme derivative:

```
(define l (list #\c #\m #\a #\y #\k))
(map integer->char
     (sort (map char->integer l) <))
```

Output:

```
'(#\a #\c #\k #\m #\y)
```